# How to decode protobuf base64 string to js object

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I'm try to decode protobuf message from server side (base64 string) to javascript object. Use for decode [protobuf.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js).

As doc suggest :

```
var builder = ProtoBuf.newBuilder({ convertFieldsToCamelCase: true });
var YourMessage = builder.build("YourMessage");
var buffer = ...; // E.g. a buffer received on a WebSocket
var myMessage = YourMessage.decode(buffer);
...
var b64str = ...; // E.g. a string fetched via AJAX
var myMessage = YourMessage.decode64(b64str);
```

This is how I try to do it (data - base64 string) :

```
var proto = dcodeIO.ProtoBuf;
var buffer = dcodeIO.ByteBuffer;
var b = buffer.wrap(data,"binary");
var builder = proto.newBuilder({ convertFieldsToCamelCase: true });
builder.define("Events");
var message = builder.build("Events");
var result = message.decode(b); //also try to decode base64 string - message.decode64(data);
```

I get error

> decode/decode64 undefined

Comment: I can't see in that code where you are loading in the proto file or text that defines your protobuf schema. You should have a line like `ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile("tests/example1.proto", builder);` telling it where your .proto definition is. That would explain the builder not constructing messages and the null values you are getting

Comment: @PhilipPryde thanks, I losted descriptor.

Comment: Did that work for you then? if so I'll bump my comment to an answer...

Comment: @PhilipPryde yes, sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing the line to import the proto definition as below (where tests/example1.proto is your file name)

`ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile("tests/example1.proto", builder);`

or if loading from proto string

`ProtoBuf.loadProto(...protoString..., "example1.proto");`

without this the builder will say undefined because there is nothing for it to build its definition with